# VMware ESXi: best practices for running off USB thumb drive?

Tags: vmware, usb-flash-drive

I'm running VMware ESXi 5.5 (and 6.0) on my servers off of a SanDisk Cruzer Fit 16GB flash drive.  The VMs are stored on a RAID array of internal physical drives on the server.

If that flash drive fails, I'm assuming my system will be inoperable.

Two questions:

1. How to restore the system to operation assuming the flash drive fails?  If I reinstalled ESXi on a new identical thumb drive, would VMware automatically see the already-existing VMs on the server's internal hard drives?  Or is the process for discovering the existing VMs relatively painless?
2. How can I maintain redundancy for my flash drive in case of failure?  Can I have two flash drives connected and automatically backup / mirror the first drive to the second?

Comment: Consider posting this on VMware Communities as well, they are really helpful! https://communities.vmware.com/welcome

Answer (score 1):

1. You can reinstall ESXi to a new USB flash drive, and it will see your existing VMFS datastore so you can browse that datastore, and re-reigster the vms in inventory.

   From VMware KB Article [2004784](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2004784)

   > If you have a local datastore containing production information and have completed the installation on a replacement USB flash drive or SD flash card in a disaster recovery scenario, you may be required perform these additional steps:
   >
   > 1. Connect to the ESXi host using the vSphere Client or add the ESXi host to an existing vCenter Server implementation.
   > 2. Click the host.
   > 3. Click the Configuration tab.
   > 4. Click Storage.
   > 5. Click Rescan to ensure you can see all datastores.
   > 6. Browse the datastore and register any virtual machines that are located on the datastores

   You can also [backup your ESXi configuration](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2042141) with vSphere Command-Line or PowerCLI.
2. To the best of my knowledge you cannot use USB drives in any type of highly available scenario. There are [server modules](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/poweredge-idsdm-whitepaper-en.pdf) that allow you to have dual SD cards that run in in a redundant fashion, but those have dedicated hardware to support that functionality, and it is transparent to the ESXi installation.

   Also from VMware KB Article [2004784](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2004784)

   > VMware recommends using a retail purchased USB flash drive of 16 GB or larger so that the "extra" flash cells can **prolong the life of the boot** media [...].